# Selecting items in MySQL database within a certain day

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a graph of items on a certain day using data from a MySQL database. I have the query

```
SELECT * FROM activities 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 3600 * 7 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 3600 * 6
```

to select items from x days ago (where the 7 and 6 can vary in order to select the day), but it's returning an empty set in my database for some reason.

Comment: Are you using PHP or another language that handle unix timestamp ? If yo, generate the time before and pass it to MySQL after.

Comment: I am, but when I go into PHPMyAdmin and put in that SQL it still does the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure that you have data on that day? What is the type of the timestamp column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
 SELECT * FROM activities
 WHERE  date(timestamp) between start_date
 and DATE_SUB(start_date,interval x day))
```

Replace `start_date` with your `startdate`  and `x with interval`

Answer (score 1):

1. Check warnings (SHOW WARNINGS). It probably looks like this:

   Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
   Message: Incorrect datetime value: '1332194471' for column 'timestamp' at row 1
2. In case it is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column:

   SELECT * FROM activities WHERE DATE(timestamp) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL x DAY);

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'activities' WHERE 'timestamp'< UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 3600 * 7 AND 'timestamp'> UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 3600 * 6
```

I am really not sure but, it may work.

Comment: -1 Did you try this? 1. single quotes delimit string literals in SQL, so *activities* and *timestamp* are strings not identifiers;  2. upper and lower bound are reversed, so the WHERE clause can't match anything; 3. fully mimicking BETWEEN semantics requires >= and <=.